# (Rails) Form method for To Do List quick edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do a quick edit feature in my To Do List: if the user clicks on anywhere in the red box shown (in Edit 2), he'll be redirected to the edit action in the controller.

However, which form methods should I use? The only one that worked so far was `link_to`: I simply added the link to the title. But it doesn't span the entire red box. Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

Partial `task` that represents 1. checkbox 2. title and 3. actions (show, edit, tags)

```
<% status = get_status(task) %>
<section id=<%=task.id%> class=<%=status%>>
<!-- checkbox -->
    <%= form_with scope: task, url: completed_task_path(task), method: :patch do |form|%>
        <%= form.check_box :completed%>
<!-- Title: I want make this a box -->
        <%= task.title %>

<!-- Labels -->
        <section class="actions">
            <%= render partial: 'actions', locals: {task: task} %>
        </section>
<!-- Details -->
        <section class= "details">
            <%= task.details %>
        </section>
    <% end %>
</section>
```

**Edit 2** 
Here's how it looks like currently.

[TODO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUFzC.png)

Comment: Paste the html code from the view file.

Comment: Done, thank u for ur time!

Comment: You can wrap the whole `task` partial into a `<%= link_to do <% end %>` block.

Comment: do you want some features like edit on the same place or you want to redirect to particular page

Comment: @Emu Doing so makes the actions links to the edit action; they are themselves links to other actions. I'd like only the red box to link to the edit action. I've uploaded in edit 2 how it looks like currently. Thank u for ur time!

Comment: @CryptexTechnologies Thank you for your time but my question is on the "styling" - how do i make the red box redirect to the edit action in the controller instead of the title itself.
I've managed to implement ajax already.

Comment: Ok thanks @LarryLaw for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is via javascript (and a little bit of rails). You did not upload the html for the partial, but I assume it has a div wrapping the checkbox and the label. You could add something like:

```
<div onClick="window.location.href = '#{your_controller_action_path}'"></div>
```

Where "your_controller_action_path" is the helper method for the url where you want to redirect.

Comment: Update for future ref:
1. Issue with div is that it is a block, thus it indents a new line. To circumvent this, I had to make it a flex box that is 1) no wrap 2) horizontal direction 3) justify content center.
2. Issue with passing in the link is that it becomes a HTML instead of an JS request. To circumvent this, I had to pass in a javascript function into on click which takes in `my_controller_action_path`, and define an ajax get request on this string.
Thank you for pointing me in the right direction @Rodrigo Echeconea!